# Splunk Count Specific String in a Field

Tags: splunk-query

In Splunk, I need to get the count of events from the below msg field value which matches factType=COMMERCIAL and has filters.

Using the basic Splunk query with wildcard does not work efficiently. Could you please assist

```
app_name="ABC" cf_space_name=prod  msg="*/facts?factType=COMMERCIAL&sourceSystem=ADMIN&sourceOwner=ABC&filters*"
```

> msg: abc.asia - [2021-08-23T00:27:08.152+0000] "GET
> /facts?factType=COMMERCIAL&sourceSystem=ADMIN&sourceOwner=ABC&filters=%257B%2522stringMatchFilters%2522:%255B%257B%2522key%2522:%2522BFEESCE((json_data-%253E%253E'isNotSearchable')::boolean,%2520false)%2522,%2522value%2522:%2522false%2522,%2522operator%2522:%2522EQ%2522%257D%255D,%2522multiStringMatchFilters%2522:%255B%257B%2522key%2522:%2522json_data-%253E%253E'id'%2522,%2522values%2522:%255B%25224970111%2522%255D%257D%255D,%2522containmentFilters%2522:%255B%255D,%2522nestedMultiStringMatchFilter%2522:%255B%255D,%2522nestedStringMatchFilters%2522:%255B%255D%257D&sorts=%257B%2522sortOrders%2522:%255B%257B%2522key%2522:%2522id%2522,%2522order%2522:%2522DESC%2522%257D%255D%257D&pagination=null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp msg=*
| rex field=msg "factType=(?<facttype>\w+).(?<params>.+)"
| stats count by facttype params
| fields - count
| search facttype="commercial"
```

The [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) will extract the facttype and any following parameters (note - if the URL is submitted with the arguments in a different order, you'll need to adjust the [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/omCc6k/1))

Then use a `| stats count by` to bin them together

Lastly, search only where there is *both* a `facttype="commercial"` *and* the URL has additional parameters